# Pythonic way for calculating complex terms in Pandas (values bigger or equal to a number divided by the length of a list)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
simple_list=[[3.0, [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5]]]
simple_list.append([0.25, [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6]])

df4=pd.DataFrame(simple_list,columns=['col1','col2'])
```

I want create a new column called `new_col`, in which there's the following calculation:

The number of occurrences of elements in `col2` that are bigger or equal than the given number in `col1`, divided by the length of the list in `col2`.

i.e.,

first value in `new_col` will be: 0.6 (there are 3 numbers bigger than 3.0, and 5 is the length of this list)

second value in `new_col` will be: 0.6667 (there are 4 numbers bigger than 0.25, and 6 is the length of this list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.squeeze`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html) with [`DataFrame.eval`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html) for compare columns and then `mean` per index:

```
df4['new'] = df4.explode('col2').eval('col1 < col2').mean(level=0)
```

Or convert lists to DataFrame and before `mean` create missing values by `df1`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df4['col2'].tolist(), index=df4.index)
df4['new'] = df1.gt(df4['col1'], axis=0).mask(df1.isna()).mean(axis=1)
```

---

Slowier solutions:

Or is possible use list comprehension with convert list to numpy array:

```
df4['new'] = [(np.array(b) > a).mean() for a, b in df4[['col1','col2']].to_numpy()]
```

Another idea with [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df4['new'] = df4.apply(lambda x: (np.array(x['col2']) > x['col1']).mean(), axis=1)
```

---

```
print (df4)
   col1                            col2       new
0  3.00       [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5]  0.600000
1  0.25  [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6]  0.666667
```

**Perfromance**:

```
df4=pd.DataFrame(simple_list,columns=['col1','col2'])

df4 = pd.concat([df4] * 10000, ignore_index=True)


In [262]: %%timeit
     ...: df1 = pd.DataFrame(df4['col2'].tolist(), index=df4.index)
     ...: df4['new'] = df1.gt(df4['col1'], axis=0).mask(df1.isna()).mean(axis=1)
     ...: 
40.9 ms ± 3.03 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [263]: %timeit df4.explode('col2').eval('col1 < col2').mean(level=0)
97.2 ms ± 13.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [264]: %timeit [(np.array(b) > a).mean() for a, b in df4[['col1','col2']].to_numpy()]
305 ms ± 12 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [265]: %timeit df4.apply(lambda x: (np.array(x['col2']) > x['col1']).mean(), axis=1)
1.23 s ± 32.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```